# How to add a tooltip for horizontal LED fusion chart

Tags: asp.net, graph, charts, fusioncharts

I am using the following horizontal LED fusion chart in application http://www.fusioncharts.com/widgets/Gallery/HLED4.html how can i add a tooltip to indicate the current value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Horizontal LED gauge of the FusionWidgets pack does not support tool-tip, as of now.